# Azure virtual machine cost and pricing questions

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014, azure-virtual-machine

I have an A-Series, A0 at $18.22 ($0.025/hr) Azure Virtual Machine setup.

1. How much is the cost to update software in the virtual machine. For
   example, if I wish to do a Windows Update from the Virtual Machine's
   Control Panel, is there any cost associated with this?
2. If I wish to copy an installation file for Windows SQL Server 2014
   from a Remote Desktop Connection, am I charged for the data transfer
   of this file?
3. I am wanting to setup IIS for a MVC 5 internet application with my
   own SQL Server 2014 installation. Are there any costs associated
   with setting this up and having it running?
4. Other than the $18.22 ($0.025/hr), what other costs are there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the details on licensing:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/

Inbound data is not charged, but egress is charged. Pricing for egress is located here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/